# angular js ng-click ng-controller and ng-app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I can't get angularJS to recognize a variable defined in ng-app, ng-controller, or ng-click.

3 sets of codes that I tried so far are:

```html
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <script>
            var app = angular.module('ngClickApp', []);
            app.controller('ngClickCtrl', function ($scope) {
               $scope.clkCount = 0;
            });
         </script>
         <th ng-app="ngClickApp" ng-controller="ngClickCtrl">
             <button class="some-scss" ng-click="clkCount = clkCount +1">
                 <b>someCol {{ clkCount }}</b>
             </button>
         </th>
```

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr ng-app="ngClickApp">
         <th><button class="some-scss" ng-controller="ngClickCtrl"><b>someCol {{ clkCount }}</b></button></th>
         <script>
            var app = angular.module('ngClickApp', []);
            app.controller('ngClickCtrl', function ($scope) {
               $scope.clkCount = 0;
            });
         </script>
```

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr ng-app="ngClickApp">
         <th><button class="some-scss" ng-controller="ngClickCtrl"><b>someCol {{ clkCount }}</b></button></th>
         <script>
            var ngClickCtrl = function ($scope) {
               $scope.clkCount = 0;
            };
         </script>
```

All three of them failed to recognize clkCount.

Examples that I found do not use table format. (https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/angularjs/angularjs-scope) or (https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-ng-click-event-function-with-example)

Also, just out of curiosity, to test ng-click in the first code, I defined some function and called it in ng-click, but it did not work.

```
clickTest() {
   console.log('1');
}

<th><button class="some-scss" ng-click="clickTest()">someButton</button></th>
```

did not print 1 when I clicked "someButton" whereas

```
clickTest() {
   console.log('1');
}

<th><button class="some-scss" (click)="clickTest()">someButton</button></th>
```

did print 1 when I clicked the same button.

So, I was wondering if ng-app, ng-controller, and ng-click need some type of initiation or they have to be in the `<tbody>` or any other suggestions why all the above codes that worked just fine in examples do not work in the tables.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн https://jsfiddle.net/2zbwvd9e/1/ here is the jsfiddle with the very first code snippet. When I click the button, {{clkCount} should change, starting from 0 but it does not.

Comment: You have not added any reference of angularjs file in the demo. Also, the ng-app="ngClickApp" ng-controller="ngClickCtrl" needs to be bound to a parent container not to a sibling. Here is the working demo: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sde1ckau/)

Comment: @palaѕн My apologies. It is the first time I used Jsfiddle and I am not sure what you mean by "any reference of angularjs file". To make it proper in the future, what should I have added in the link I provided? Also, I bound ng-app and ng-controller to parent container as you suggested, but it still does not work. Does the <script> ... </script> part have to be in .ts file in order for this to work? Can I not use it in the html?

Comment: You can read about js fiddle setting [here](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/panels-settings). I don't know what setup you have in your end so can't help you there. But you can add script in HTML but keep it at bottom inside body tag, so that it only works once dom is fully loaded.

Comment: @palaѕн Thanks. In Jsfiddle, I moved the controller function to html view with <script></script> and it works fine anywhere, but when I do the same in Angular html, it still does not work. I really appreciate your help, but do you have any idea why it works in Jsfiddle but not in Angular? Is it the reference problem that you pointed out earlier?

Comment: Not getting what you mean by "it works in Jsfiddle but not in Angular" please explain so that I can help.

Comment: @palaѕн So, I cut the controller function from JavaScript + Angular JS 1.4.8 and pasted it into HTML in Jsfiddle. It works fine, but when I do it in actual program, NOT IN Jsfiddle, it still does not work even after binding ng-app and ng-controller to parent container. And if I change the setting to Angular JS 2.0.0-alpha.47 the code broke down in Jsfiddle no matter where the controller function is defined, whether in HTML or in JS. So, I am guessing I am using Angular JS 2.0.0-alpha.47?

Comment: Angular JS 2.x is completely different from Angular JS 1.x. Here is a [link](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/difference-between-angular-1-x-and-angular-2/) This fiddle demo will not work at all in Angular JS 2.x

Comment: @palaѕн I believe I am using Angular JS 2.x. All the features that I am using (previous colleague actually set it up) look a lot like Angular JS 2.x features introduced in the link you provided. Like I said, I did not set up this project, I was only assigned to it after person-in-charge moved, so hence lack of info on my part. Then, can this fiddle demo be applied to Angular JS 2.x with modification? Or is it completely different area of work?

Comment: I will see if I can create a demo using A2 after some time using codesandbox, as I don't think in jsfiddle we can create A2 demos due to some limitations. Going offline now.

Comment: @palaѕн Thanks so much for your help! Hope it is not too complicated. I will also see if I can find some solutions. If you come up with demo, please let me know! Thanks again.

Comment: I have created a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-2-2vgu7?file=/src/app/app.component.html) This `/src/app/app.component.html` has the HTML code and in `app.component.ts` we only need to declare scope value `clkCount`

Comment: @palaѕн Thanks so much! Your demo solved the mystery! I really appreciate your help on this one! Glad to have found out that I am using Angular 2.x the hard way though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table>
     <thead>
      <tr ng-app="ngClickApp">
         <th>
           <button class="some-scss" ng-controller="ngClickCtrl" ng-click="clkCount=clkCount+1"><b>someCol {{clkCount}}</b></button>
          </th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<script>
   var app = angular.module('ngClickApp', []);
   app.controller('ngClickCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.clkCount = 0;
```

```js
var app = angular.module('ngClickApp', []);
app.controller('ngClickCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clkCount = 0;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr ng-app="ngClickApp">
        <th>
          <button class="some-scss" ng-controller="ngClickCtrl" ng-click="clkCount=clkCount+1"><b>someCol {{clkCount}}</b></button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi,
You should not put the script inside a table. Need to keep the script in a separate file or at the end of your HTML or just above the body tag inside HTML so that the page loads faster as javascript code can block/delay the loading process.
Try not to use scripts, CSS or HTML in the same file to keep the code easy to read, maintain and modify.
Thanks